# try to create CCSpriteFrame but get nil values

Tags: software-engineering, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to animate a CCSprite in cocos2d v3 following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645953/how-to-animate-ccsprite-in-cocos2d-3-x), but I'm getting the following error message in Log:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
 insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

This is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *animationFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    int frameCount = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        CCSpriteFrame *spriteFrame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hero-%d.png", i]];

            [animationFrames addObject:spriteFrame]; //ERROR OCCUR THIS LINE

        frameCount++;
        if (frameCount == 8) break;
    }
```

The problem is that all spriteFrames are nil, but I don't why. I already tested the i values with NSLog, and also tried to add hero-1.png to a CCSprite object and works fine. I also tried to add all fixed hero-1.png in all frames to verify if the problem was with i variable. But didn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work! in cocos2d 3.x

NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray array];

```
int frameCount = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {           
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dice0%d.png",i]];

        [frames addObject:frame];
    }

CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:frames.firstObject];
[self addChild:sprite]; // or to whatever object it will be parented to
sprite.position = ccp(WIDTH*0.5, HEIGHT*0.5);

CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:0.5];
CCAction *animateAction = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
[sprite runAction:animateAction];
```